# gh-pages -d build fails on 'npm run deploy'

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I am trying to deploy my react app to the GitHub pages but I have encountered the following error:

```
The build folder is ready to be deployed.
To publish it at https://jatinkumarg.github.io/personal-portfolio, run:

  npm run deploy


> personal-portfolio@0.1.0 deploy C:\react-projects\personal-portfolio
> gh-pages -d build

Cloning into 'node_modules\gh-pages\.cache\git@github.com!jatinkumarg!personal-portfolio.git'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! personal-portfolio@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the personal-portfolio@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jatin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-23T04_40_54_788Z-debug.log
```

- I have already set-up and tested my ssh key, it works fine.
- There is only one remote url i.e. origin(SSH)

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "personal-portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://jatinkumarg.github.io/personal-portfolio",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^1.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

At this point, I have no idea what's wrong. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `PRO` plan to use GitHub pages on a private repository.

You can try adding a SSH identity in ~/.ssh/config

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /Users/myusername/.ssh/my_github_ssh_private_key_registered_on_github
```

Comment: I have PRO Github account

Comment: Did you do something in your project or folder with ```sudo``` command? For example you cloned project with ```sudo```

Comment: You can try adding a SSH identity in ~/.ssh/config
```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /Users/myusername/.ssh/my_github_ssh_private_key_registered_on_github
```

Comment: But there is no config file in .ssh folder. Do you want me to creat one?

Comment: Yes, please create ```config``` in file ```~/.ssh/```

Comment: I added SSH identity but the problem still exists. Also, I have changed my repo to public.

Comment: Update: It works now. Due to some reason, my old GitHub was logged on my local so I added that username to the collaborators of my project and it worked. By any chance do you know how I can remove my old GitHub account from the local

Answer (score 0):

it didnt help me, but here is my solution:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY_NAME.git
```

You will recieve smtn like this:

```
npm run deploy

> ravenous@0.1.0 predeploy C:\Users\peter\ravenous
> npm run build


> ravenous@0.1.0 build C:\Users\peter\ravenous
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled with warnings.

./src/components/SearchBar/SearchBar.js
  Line 84:21:  The href attribute is required for an anchor to be keyboard accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide an href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid

./src/components/Business/Business.js
  Line 9:55:   Using target="_blank" without rel="noopener noreferrer" is a security risk: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener  react/jsx-no-target-blank
  Line 17:21:  Using target="_blank" without rel="noopener noreferrer" is a security risk: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener  react/jsx-no-target-blank

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

File sizes after gzip:

  40.23 KB  build\static\js\2.c4f174a4.chunk.js
  1.76 KB   build\static\js\main.f787394e.chunk.js
  1.08 KB   build\static\css\main.551e99bf.chunk.css
  783 B     build\static\js\runtime-main.647a42cc.js

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /personalportfolio/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
To publish it at http://PetrMitin.github.io/personalportfolio , run:

  npm run deploy

Find out more about deployment here:

  bit.ly/CRA-deploy


> ravenous@0.1.0 deploy C:\Users\peter\ravenous
> gh-pages -d build


*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'peter@LAPTOP-FRARNQJG.(none)')

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ravenous@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ravenous@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\peter\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-07T23_02_19_256Z-debug.log
```

If you did, you are on the right way!

Then pass required info by entering in cmd or whatever:

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

And try to run:

```
npm run deploy
```

I believe that i`ve helped you to resolve your question.